# Docker container/image is not rebuilding automatically on code amendment

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

In short i want my docker container/image rebuild automatically whenever i write a new chunk of functions.
 I have created a node app, running the server in Docker container via compose.
The container works fine, however whenever i make changing in the files or directory it doesn't render the changes automatically. I need to rebuild the directory again via

```
    $ docker-compose up --build
```

so that the changes may take effect.

is there any solution that i might not need to rebuild the container  manually?

Regards.

Comment: You need to hook it up to the build pipelines using Jenkins, circleCi, GoCD or similar

Comment: Have you considered using a volume to mount the application code in the container?

Comment: Thanks Boynux, and pdoherty926 :- yeah i am going for the volumes concept. i've tried it even, i just have one question, that writing volumes directive in my docker-compose.yml file would create a volume?? or i have to manually create a volume first and then it would refer it in the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You either want to look at some kind of delivery pipeline tool as Boynux suggests, btw Dockerhub can watch github for checkins and trigger automatic image builds.

Or you can mount the code into the container using a volume so that changes are picked up.

The option you pick depends on your philosophy / delivery pipeline.

Comment: Hi JHarris: Thanks
yeah i am going for the volumes concept. i've tried it even, i just have one question, that writing volumes directive in my docker-compose.yml file would create a volume?? or i have to manually create a volume first and then it would refer it in the file ?

Comment: You can create volumes directly in a docker-compose file, see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: Hi JHarris:    I have been working for it, However i couldn't resolve the issure so far, here is my docker-compose.yml file 
 
`www:
 container_name: app_www_1 
 build: .
 volumes:
  - /var/lib/docker/volumes/app_ww
  - /opt/apnosrest:/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_ww
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache
 ports:
  - "80:3000"
 expose:
  - "80" `

I am not getting my required work done. i.e, automatic rendering of change made in code.

here is the list of volumes created in the system:


`$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               app_ww `

Comment: Doesn't look like you're using volumes correctly. Please post your docker-compose.yml file in your question, and what directories on your _local_ that you're expecting to be mounted into your _container_.

Comment: nodemon worked for me perfectly. thanks for your response @JHarris.